# C++ getpid() vs syscall(39)?

Tags: c++, linux, macos, unix, system-calls

I read that syscall(39) returns the current process id (pid)

Then why these 2 programs output 2 different numbers?

```
int main() {
    long r = syscall(39);
    printf("returned %ld\n", r);
    return 0;
}
```

and:

```
int main() {
    long r = getpid();
    printf("returned %ld\n", r);
    return 0;
}
```

I am running my program in clion, and when I change the first line I get different result which is really strange.

Running the code in the answers I got (in macos):

```
returned getpid()=9390 vs. syscall(39)=8340
```

which is really strange.

In ubuntu I got same pid for both, why is that?

Comment: What specific result do you observe from each?

Comment: What environment are these running upon?

Comment: Why are you expecting them to return the same number *at every invocation*? Different runs of the same program usually get different PIDs.

Comment: The process id is assigned by the OS when the program starts. Different runs of the same program can have a different process id, as can different runs of different programs.

Comment: Why not just print both in the same program/run...?!?

Comment: @underscore_d please see my update

Comment: `syscall(39)` is "get the process id" on Linux.  It means something else on macOS (it means "get the parent process id").

Comment: @Eljay isn't macos part of linux? (same family)

Comment: *isn't macos part of linux* Uh... no. Not at all. They're completely different operating systems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Making system calls by their number is not going to be portable.

Indeed, we see that 39 is [**getpid**](https://filippo.io/linux-syscall-table/) on Linux, but [**getppid**](https://sigsegv.pl/osx-bsd-syscalls/) ("get parent pid") on macOS.

`getpid` on macOS is 20.

So that's why you see a different result between `getpid()` and `syscall(39)` on macOS.

Note that macOS, being a BSD kernel derivative, is not related to Linux in any way. It can't possibly be, since it's closed-source.

Comment: Just curious-  where did you find that syscall mapping? I only saw this page that shows 39 is getpid on mac https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1504.3.12/bsd/kern/syscalls.master

Comment: @GandhiGandhi your source is fine, it also says 39 is getppid, not getpid.

Comment: @rustyx, might be worth mentioning the existence of `SYS_foobar` defines.

Comment: Aha, tricky double p...  @john This is the right answer.

Answer (score 3):

There's one key detail that's missing here -- every time you run the program, your OS assigns it a new PID. Calling the same program twice in a row will likely return different PIDs - so what you're describing isn't a good way to test the difference between `getpid()` and `syscall(39)`.

Here's a better program to compare the two that calls both functions in the same program.

```
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    long pid1 = getpid();
    long pid2 = syscall(39);
    printf("returned getpid()=%ld vs. syscall(39)=%ld\n", pid1, pid2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But when I change my program to version 1 it prints the same old pid1, when I change it to version 2 prints pid2

Comment: please see my update, it's much more clear now

Comment: Gotchya- much clearer question. I think the primary reason is that `syscall()` is not portable between operating systems -- although from these documents https://opensource.apple.com/source/xnu/xnu-1504.3.12/bsd/kern/syscalls.master it seems like `39` should also be equivalent to `getpid()` on MacOs. Can you update your question again with the full source including the `#include` lines?